# Como mostrar los Datos seleccionados(mediante JSON) de un Select Multiple

Tags: php, javascript, html, json

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
     <title></title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">

     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/funciones.js"></script>
     <link href="css/jquery.multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>    
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <center>
      <br/>
      <br/><br/>
      <label>DNI</label>
    <input type="text" id="dni"> 

    <br/><br/>
    <label>NOMBRE</label>
    <input type="text" id="nombre"> 

    </br></br>
    <select class="test" id="tecnologia" name="tecnologia[]" multiple="multiple">
     <option value="2g">2G</option> 
      <option value="3g">3G</option> 
     <option value="4g">4G</option> 
     <option value="tdd">TDD</option>
      </select>
     <script>
    $('document').ready(function(){
        $('#tecnologia').multiselect({
            columns: 1,
            placeholder: 'Selecciona la tecnologia',
            search: true,
            selectAll: true
        });
    });
</script>

    <button onclick="anadir();">Añadir</button>
    <input type="submit" onclick="buscar()" value="buscar">

</body>
</html>
```

tengo un codigo html en el cual estoy usando jquery.multiselect.css,jquery.multiselect.js,jquery-2.1.3.js y lo enlazo a una javascript funciones.js.

al momento de llamar mis valores de la bd mediante JSON,no los muestra, pero si son llamados.osea que los cuadros de check no salen marcados, y quisiera saber como puedo arreglar eso.

```
function buscar(){

    var parametros={"dni": $("#dni").val(),}

    $.ajax({

            type: 'post',
            url: '../lunes-5/buscardatos.php',
            data: parametros,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(d){
                $("#nombre").val(d[0]);



                $.each(d[1].split(","), function(i,e){
                    $("#tecnologia option[value='"+e+"']").prop("selected",true);
                });
                $("#tecnologia").multiselect("refresh");

            }
        });
}
```

en el JS realizo un refresh para q me refresque los datos pero no lo hace... hay alguna manera de que me muestre los check del multiselect marcados?

```
  <?php
   $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  mysql_select_db("archivos",$con);

  $dni=$_POST["dni"];
  $rs=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clie  WHERE dni='$dni'");

  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);

  $datos_a_enviar = array($row['nombre'],$row['tecnologia']);

  echo json_encode($datos_a_enviar);
?>
```

Comment: podrias poner el json resultante

Comment: ok, modificare mi pregunta..para que se vea el JSON

Comment: que datos trae d[1]  de tu javascript ya que mediante esto se puede realizar validaciones y establecer las selecciones en tu mutiselect

Comment: si vas aqui ya esta resuelto ello: https://jsfiddle.net/hL2jt9n0/3/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750253/bootstrap-multiselectrefresh-is-not-working-properly/38703694#38703694

Comment: el d[1] trae valores d mi la base de datos en la que esta almacenada lo que ya se habia seleccionado al momento de guarada